# install webpack using npm gives max call stack exceeded errror

Tags: npm, webpack

```
npm i -D webpack
```

gives me the 
npm ERR! Maximum call stack size exceeded

do i need to run the  below command to install webpack

```
npm install --no-optional webpack --save-dev
```

why i am not able to install webpack with npm i webpack ?

i am using below versions

```
node - 8.11.1
npm -5.6.0
```

**package.json**

```
"dependencies": {
    "react": "^16.5.2",
    "react-dom": "^16.5.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel": "^6.23.0",
    "babel-core": "^6.26.3",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.4",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",
    "http-server": "^0.11.1",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.1.2",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.1.9"
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend the installation process as described on the [webpack website](https://webpack.js.org/guides/installation/)

```
npm install --save-dev webpack
```

Or if you want a specific version

```
npm install --save-dev webpack@<version>
```

Note: If your using webpack v4 or later you also need to install the CLI

```
npm install --save-dev webpack-cli
```

If `--save-dev` argument doesn't work try deleting `package-lock.json` and retry

If you're still experiencing problems, [here's](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/17056) a link to a GitHub issue with more solutions

Comment: but i tried this npm install --save-dev webpack, its giving me maximum call stack exceeded?

Comment: @DILEEPTHOMAS Can you give us any more info? Also try `npm rebuild` and retry

Comment: npm rebuild is mostly used when you change a package exist version? what i am facing is i am not able to download the package ? eventhough i tried npm rebuild after that i exexuted npm i webpack same error

Comment: @DILEEPTHOMAS I found a Issue on GitHub with multiple people having the same/ a similar problem, here it is: https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/17056

Comment: i removed the  package-lock.json and run the command it got worked. You can udpate your answer. Thanks for the help :) i had already gone through this thread and tried removing it at that time it didn't worked anyways this time it worked  :)

Comment: @DILEEPTHOMAS updated the, and no problem, here to help :)